# PHP Multidimensional Array Searching (edit and save results)

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

So i have an array from a file that looks like this

```
0:uploads/Zdjęcie0232.jpg
0:uploads/Zdjęcie0222.jpg
0:uploads/duparomana.jpg
0:uploads/dddfsdfsd.jpg
0:uploads/6.jpg
```

it's made by upload that looks like this

```
<?php
$licznik = 0;
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {

}
/* Check file size

}*/
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file//
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

        // open file to read
        $fp = fopen("database.dat", "r");   
        $separator=':';
        //read data
        $stareDane = fread($fp, filesize("database.dat"));
        // close file
        fclose($fp);
        // create new data
        $noweDane = $licznik . $separator . $target_file;
        $noweDane .= PHP_EOL . $stareDane;
        // open file to write
        $fp = fopen("database.dat", "w");
        // save data
        fputs($fp, $noweDane);
        // close file
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

echo "Zaraz nastąpi przekierowanie";
sleep (3);
header("Location: /index.php?filename=$target_file", true, 301);
exit();


?>
```

So in the section

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {

}
```

I want to search if in database.dat exist line with path to file. Next i want to increase number before `:` by one and then leave without saving this file (picture) second time in folder. i tried a little bit with posts that were already made here but I really stuck here.

The example of array that i stucked with:

```
array (size=24)   0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string 'uploads/Zdjęcie0232.jpg ' (length=25)   1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string 'uploads/Zdjęcie0228.jpg ' (length=25)   2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string 'uploads/Zdjęcie0262.jpg ' (length=25)
```

Comment: file_exists() is the right way to check if a file already exists.  I am not sure that I understand your question.

Comment: I have a .dat file with files saved as [points]:[filename] and i want to check in this .dat file if it exists and edit number of [points]

Comment: And you already know how to loop through the files.  You just want to figure out how to check if the file exists and change the file name if it does?

Comment: If file name are unique, you can try to create a array as `['filename1' => 0, 'filename2' => 1, ...]` and save as [php serialize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or as a [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @ChrisStrickland yes i know how to loop throgh 
`$arr = explode("\n", $file);
foreach ($arr as $key => $dat){
   $arr[$key] = explode(":", $dat);
}`
But the problem is i dont know how to take out of this these values and operate on them for example i want to know which row in `$arr[][]` it is and change value of `$arr[][0]` 
I got stucked in this point and its last thing i need to do in this sprint...

Comment: @DzikaSuślica: so you just want to know how to update the line in the dat file if the file exists?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland yes. For example i want to upload file `uploads/Zdjęcie0232.jpg` and if it exists it changes number from 0 to 1 and saves it in database.dat

Answer (score 0):

Unless database.dat is very large, I would probably just read the entire file into memory and do a replace on that, then overwrite.  You can try something like this.  It uses a regular expression to find the data and calculate the new number.

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {

    $matches = false;
    $pattern = "~(\d+)(:".$target_file."$)~";
    $data = file_get_contents('database.dat');
    preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);

    if($matches) {
        $oldLine = $matches[0];
        $newLine = ($matches[1]+1).$matches[2];
        $newData = str_replace($oldLine, $newLine, $data);
        file_put_contents('database.dat', $newData, LOCK_EX);
    }

}
```

Does that do what you want?

Comment: Can you explain me how it works?
i tested it and the digit doesnt change
`0:uploads/Zdjęcie0232.jpg
0:uploads/Zdjęcie0232.jpg
0:uploads/Zdjęcie0232.jpg
0:uploads/Zdjęcie0228.jpg
0:uploads/Zdjęcie0262.jpg`

Comment: Sure, which part?  The regular expression (preg_replace) or the data update?

Comment: i dont really know how this works, this pattern doesnt looks understable for me

Comment: The pattern is just (\d+) to look for a number then : which is part of the line we're looking for, then $target_file, which is the file we're looking for, and $ which signals the end of the line.  Can you echo $newName to see what it contains?  I think I see the problem, I'm about to edit.

Comment: @DzikaSuślica: check now.

Comment: i dont see anything

Comment: Now name of the file works, before it didnt work, but there is no changes in file

Comment: Great, we're getting somewhere.  Now check $data to see if it's changing there.  If not, we'll look at that part, and if it is changed there we can look at the actual write.

Comment: Ok.  Check $oldLine and $newLine.  $oldLine should have the line that you want to change, and $newLine should have what you want to change it to.  Does it?

Comment: they are the same.

Comment: use print_r($matches) to show the contents of $matches.  $matches[0] should be the line itself.  $matches[1] should be the number, and $matches[2] should be the rest of the line starting at :.  Is that what you see?